# Express routes not rendering

Tags: api, express, routes

I can't figure out why my route 'scrape will not render. I have tried everything I can think of, even changing everything to a very basic route and I just cannot get anything to work.

app.js

```
const indexRoute = require("./routes/index");
const scrapeRoute = require("./routes/scrape");

// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use(logger("dev"));

// Routes
app.use("/", indexRoute);
app.use("/scrape", scrapeRoute);

module.exports = app;
```

here is the route:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.body);
});

module.exports = router;
```

the index route works just fine. for some reason the route 'scrape' just will not work. I had logic in there to scrape a website but when that wasn't working I figured I'd change it to just a basic route to see if I'm even getting anything and now it's just sending a 404 when I go to localhost:9000/scrape

Comment: How are you generating the `/scrape` POST request?  Please show or describe how you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just going to `http://localhost:9000/scrape` in the browser, then that is a GET request, not a POST request.  And, you would need:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("hello");
});

module.exports = router;
```

To get a response from that - change to `router.get()`.  And, because it's a GET request, there is no body so `req.body` would predictably be empty for a GET request.

---

To send a POST request from a browser, you either need have the browser submit a form with `method="POST"` and `action="/scrape"` as a attributes of the `<form>` tag or you need to use Ajax to programmatically send a POST request from Javascript using the `fetch()` interface or the `XMLHttpRequest` interface.

Comment: thank you! that makes sense now. I have been confused with this for a while

Comment: @Russ - You'd have to show the actual code you're using.  The code I show in my answer will not show `{}` in the browser.

Comment: router.get("products/:productId", async (req, res) => {
 const { productId } = req.params;

 try {
  const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}&url=https://www.amazon.com/dp/${productId}`);
  const data = JSON.parse(response);
  res.render("response.ejs", { data: data });
 } catch (error) {
  res.json(error);
 }
});

This is my actual API request that is returning a 404

Comment: well thats hard to read. i should have put that in the initial question... sorry lol

Comment: @Russ - At this point, it looks like you're asking about something new beyond what you had in your original question.  I'd suggest you start a new question where you can more easily show all the relevant code.  If you drop a link to the new question as a comment here I'll take a look at it.

Comment: understandable. appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are making a post call from the client?

Comment: ah you're right. I feel dumb now. but it is returning just empty brackets { }
and it does the same thing when I put my fetch request in there

Comment: ii think that you not pass nothing in body, and your service return given body